# jquery load function for a div not working

Tags: php, jquery, load

I just want to alert 'OK' when a div with id="Box" loads. But load function is not working. Here is my code in wordpress. I have included the jquery library and other jquery is working fine.

```
jQuery(function(){

jQuery( '#Box' ).load(function() {

alert('ok');
        });

    });
```

Comment: Sorry, I have corrected my code. still not working. edited my questions

Comment: That works only with images etc.. "The load event is sent to an element when it and all sub-elements have been completely loaded. This event can be sent to any element associated with a URL: images, scripts, frames, iframes, and the window object."

Comment: It doesn't alert OK when the div loads.

Answer (score 5):

It does not work with DIV elements:

See: https://api.jquery.com/load-event/

> "The load event is sent to an element when it and all sub-elements
>   have been completely loaded. This event can be sent to any element
>   associated with a URL: images, scripts, frames, iframes, and the
>   window object."

Comment: It is possible as in jquery documentation but don't know how?$( "#book" ).load(function() {
  // Handler for .load() called.
});

Comment: What you are loading????????????????????? there is also AJAX related load function which loads data.. https://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Otherwise your div is loaded same time as your DOM.

Comment: The OP was not talking about the load event but rather the load method.

Comment: @MatthewKane read the question "I just want to alert 'OK' when a div with id="Box" loads"

Answer (score 1):

**Question:**

> I just want to alert 'OK' when a div with id="Box" loads. But load function is not working.

---

You are using `.load()`.

**Answer A :** This method will not work with a `div`.

**Answer B :** This method was deprecated in jQuery 1.8. Stop using it!

> This method is a shortcut for .on( "load", handler ).
>
> The load event is sent to an element when it and all sub-elements have
>   been completely loaded. This event can be sent to any element
>   associated with a URL: images, scripts, frames, iframes, and the
>   window object.
>
> https://api.jquery.com/load-event/

---

**Possible solution**:

Use the shorthand method `.ajax()`, `.load()`, `.get` to load content and trigger your stuff in the callback function or success handler.

> .load() Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the
>   matched element.
>
> http://api.jquery.com/load/

**Example 1**

Specify what to load in the first parameter and act in the **callback function**. The content of test.html is loaded, after that it's inserted into #box and the alert is fired.

```
$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html", function() {
    alert( "Load was performed." );
});
```

**Example 2**

Ajax Example with load alert:

```
$.get("ajax/test.html", function(data) {
    $("#box").html(data);
    alert("Ok. Load.");
});
```

You are loading `test.html` the content is returned as `data`. It is assigned as new html content to the dom element `#box`. Then you fire the `alert`.

**Example 3**

The alternative is using the `.ajax` method and define a `success` handler:

```
function getData() {
    $.ajax({
        url : 'test.html',
        type: 'GET',
        success : alert('Ok.Loaded')
    });
}
```

Comment: Actually data to be loaded is already there, I just want a message when it is loaded.

Comment: see ajax example, maybe it's ok to attach the alert there